# tuple error, no matching constructor for initialization of 'Stock'

Tags: c++

iam making a stock market game but for some reason, this same exact error pops up every time, "`/nix/store/dlni53myj53kx20pi4yhm7p68lw17b07-gcc-10.3.0/include/c++/10.3.0/tuple:1693:9: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Stock'` "

no idea of what it means. this seems to be like a individual error, one that has a diffrent solution for everyone

i tried to do things like changing the `void addStock`  by removing the `std::pair`, didnt work. i don't no what to do, any solution?

btw heres the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>

// The Stock class represents a single stock in the market.
class Stock {
public:
  // Construct a new Stock with the given name and starting price.
  Stock(const std::string& name, double price)
    : name_(name), price_(price) {}

  // Get the name of the stock.
  std::string name() const { return name_; }

  // Get the current price of the stock.
  double price() const { return price_; }

  // Update the price of the stock based on a random change.
  void updatePrice() {
    // Generate a random number in the range [-0.1, 0.1].
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-0.1, 0.1);
    double change = dis(gen);

    // Update the price of the stock by the random change.
    price_ += change;
  }

private:
  std::string name_;
  double price_;
};

// The Market class represents a collection of stocks.
class Market {
public:
  // Construct a new Market.
  Market() {}

  // Add a new stock to the market with the given name and starting price.
  void addStock(const std::string& name, double price) {
    stocks_[name] = Stock(name, price);
  }


  // Get a pointer to the stock with the given name.
  Stock* getStock(const std::string& name) {
    return &stocks_[name];
  }

  // Update the prices of all stocks in the market.
  void updatePrices() {
    for (auto& pair : stocks_) {
      pair.second.updatePrice();
    }
  }

  // A map from stock names to Stock objects.
  std::map<std::string, Stock> stocks_;
};

int main() {
  // Create a new market.
  Market market;

  // Add some stocks to the market.
  market.addStock("AAPL", 100.0);
  market.addStock("GOOG", 200.0);
  market.addStock("MSFT", 150.0);

  // Update the prices of the stocks in the market.
  market.updatePrices();

  // Print the current prices of the stocks.
  for (const auto& pair : market.stocks_) {
    std::cout << pair.second.name() << ": $" << pair.second.price() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `std::map` will default-construct an item if it's not found in the `map`. In this case you'll have default construct and then assignment, but `Stock` has no default constructor. You'll have to go for something  more complicated like `find` then `insert` or assign to the returned iterator.

Comment: I get a slightly more useful error than you seem to: *error: no matching function for call to 'Stock::Stock()* which clearly shows the default constructor is being requested. Sometimes it's worth throwing the code at multiple compilers to get a second opinion. Here we can see Visual Studio telling you almost exactly what's wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/dddrqaMr1

Comment: Could you please rewrite the headline of your question, because it is too specific on your program and stacktrace, i.e. "Problem initializing ... in Cpp, when ... "? Please have a look at guidelines of SO.